# Wallpaper services and Normal services in android

Tags: android

As per my knowledge in android we can,t specify user interface in services  but in wallpaper services it contains User interface .if wallpaper service is extension of service in android why we able to implement User interface in wallpaper services ?

Answer (score 1):

Normal service does not have a valid window of itself to display the GUI.

However, there is no such limitation of "cannot specify UI for service". In fact, think about all those "floating window" style application, they are all displaying UI via background service.

To do this, all you need is to do the following:

1. `<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`
2. mWindowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
3. mWindowManager.addView(yourView, yourViewLayoutParams);
4. mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(yourView, yourViewLayoutParams);